# android build release to beta version

Tags: android, release

I am having a prod build on play store, that build is having some bugs. So

I have fixed those bugs and released the app in Beta mode, but now I am trying to install the beta version app but how can I differentiate that build installing is the beta one not the prod.

Answer (score 0):

Your Beta version is a normal version. It has version code higher than current prod version. So if you already installed prod version, and now you want to install Beta version, System will consider that you're updating your app.
The only difference between them is: beta version is not available for every one.